# Doxygen 1.8.11 build fails with gcc620

Tags: doxygen, gcc6

I have seen all the required packages and their versions for doxygen , but building with gcc620 fails with this error:

```
 [ 26%] [BISON][constexp] Building parser with bison 3.0.4
 cd /build/iahmad/newbuild/BUILD/slc6_amd64_gcc620/external/doxygen/1.8.11-cms/doxygen-1.8.11/src &&  /build/iahmad/newbuild/slc6_amd64_gcc620/external/bison/3.0.4/bin/bison  -l -p constexpYY -d -o   /build/iahmad/newbuild/BUILD/slc6_amd64_gcc620/external/doxygen/1.8.11-   cms/build/generated_src/ce_parse.cpp constexp.y
src/CMakeFiles/_doxygen.dir/build.make:293: recipe for target 'generated_src/ce_parse.cpp' failed
make[2]: *** [generated_src/ce_parse.cpp] Error 141
make[2]: Leaving directory '/build/iahmad/newbuild/BUILD/slc6_amd64_gcc620/external/doxygen/1.8.11-cms/build'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:257: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/_doxygen.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/_doxygen.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/build/iahmad/newbuild/BUILD/slc6_amd64_gcc620/external/doxygen/1.8.11-cms/build'
Makefile:163: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
error: Bad exit status from /build/iahmad/newbuild/tmp/rpm-tmp.gybERB (%install)
RPM build errors:
Bad exit status from /build/iahmad/newbuild/tmp/rpm-tmp.gybERB 
(%install)
```

please help.

Comment: What happens with the current version (1.8.12) of doxygen?

Comment: hi albert , the same error

Comment: I don't have a gcc 6(.2)  version available so can not do ant tests. Which OS are you using? Are there ant further error messages / possibilities to increase the verbosity level of the compiler? Can you post the line 293 of .../_doxygen.dir/build.make? any idea where the "-l -p constexpYY" comes from / are they still present in the 1.8.12 version (I don't see them)?

Comment: i am building on centos6 , which flags should i add to dig deep into the error?

Comment: I would try to execute, by hand / outside of make, one by one the commands as shown in the error message to see what happens and giving you the possibility to see what happens. Would be interesting to see where the error comes from. The "-l -p constexpYY" comes from the setting of YACC_FLAGS